# VideoView crop_center аналог

Tags: android, videoview, java

Требуется воспроизвести видео в полноэкранном режиме.  
Но не просто полноэкранном, а сделать аналог **crop_center** ImageView.  
То есть что бы видео занимало весь экран по меньшему размеру.  
Гугл предоставил несколько костылей, но я все еще питаю надежду на элегантное решение...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*У меня уже в традиции отвечать на свои вопросы...*  
Дело в том, что `VideoView(SurfaceView)` оптимизирован отображать контент как можно лучше в автоматическом режиме, и у меня так и не получилось его заставить отображать, как мне надо.  
Пришлось вместо него использовать `TextureView`:

```
//store the SurfaceTexture to set surface for MediaPlayer
mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new SurfaceTextureListener() {
@Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface,
            int width, int height) {
        FullScreenActivity.this.mSurface = surface;

    }
```

....

```
Surface s = new Surface(mSurface);
mPlayer = mp;
mp.setSurface(s);

scaleVideo(mp);//<-- this function scales video to run cropped
```

....

```
private void scaleVideo(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {

        LayoutParams videoParams = (LayoutParams) mTextureView
                .getLayoutParams();
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        FullScreenActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(dm);

        final int height = dm.heightPixels;
        final int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int videoHeight = mPlayer.getVideoHeight();
        int videoWidth = mPlayer.getVideoWidth();
        double hRatio = 1;

        hRatio = (height * 1.0 / videoHeight) / (width * 1.0 / videoWidth);
        videoParams.x = (int) (hRatio <= 1 ? 0 : Math.round((-(hRatio - 1) / 2)
                * width));
        videoParams.y = (int) (hRatio >= 1 ? 0 : Math
                .round((((-1 / hRatio) + 1) / 2) * height));
        videoParams.width = width - videoParams.x - videoParams.x;
        videoParams.height = height - videoParams.y - videoParams.y;
        Log.e(TAG, "x:" + videoParams.x + " y:" + videoParams.y);
        mTextureView.setScaleX(1.00001f);//<-- this line enables smoothing of the picture in TextureView.
        mTextureView.requestLayout();
        mTextureView.invalidate();

    }
```

**P. S.** Извиняюсь за использование буржуйского языка в комментариях, просто было лень переписывать их из моего ответа на **stackovrflow**